# Is there such a thing as losing your Chazaka on contracts?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

Let's say I come to court, claiming that I bought field A with a contract. That contract was found to be a forgery. I lose.

I come back the next day, saying that within the past day I bought the field. I show a contract. It was found to be a forgery.

I keep coming back day after day, hoping that *one day*, my forged contract will stand up to the court's scrutiny.

Is there a point where the court will simply refuse to believe *any* contract which I bring?

Comment: I'd assume so...

Comment: There is precedent for this sort of thing in secular Anglo Common Law traditions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frivolous_litigation), where a court can place restrictions on (but not completely bar) a litigant's ability to file future lawsuits. I would be surprised if Judaism does not have something analogous.